# Mapping Distance From Address To Public Transport

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm not really sure if this is the right place to ask, but honestly, I'm lost on even beginning to look for an answer.

I'm designing a new site that lists properties for sale in the UK - now I'd love to be able to map the nearest transport links to each property automaticially, but I have no idea how to achieve this. I've tried hiring someone on freelancer websites, but I can't find anyone to take on for the task, as presumably, I don't even know what the starting question is.

I saw this website that perfectly does what I want to achieve - http://www.freeofficefinder.com/uk/london/mayfair/berkeley-square-71855.

I'd love to do exactly what they've done, and someone on Upwork suggested that Google Map Place Search API would be able to do this, but wouldn't be able to display the actual distance from the property to the public transport, and it also wouldn't be bale to display the London Underground lines of each station as the above site has.

So the question is; what technology/process could I use to achieve this?

**TL;DR**

How to find and map distance from an address to nearest:

- Motorway junctions
- Railway stations
- Airports
- London Underground (and display lines there)

Hopefully I can find a starting point to even ask someone to develop!

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your desired required is possible by joint venture of following API's of google map.
1) first you need to fetch latitude and longitude of your current address.

2) second step to use google.maps.places to find out nearest places. 
run loop on google.maps.places response.

3) use latlang from your own address calculated in first step and latlang from loop ran on response of second step to calculate distance between these two points by using google's distance calculator API.